# Passing Variable For URL From Python To HTML In An href Link

Tags: python, html, external

I am making a forum page at the moment and would like to make it so you don't have to manually input the URL for the post, so I am trying to make the title of the post a link to the post itself. Here is my code:

Flask_app.py:

```
#...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('main.html',posts=post.query.all())
```

Main.html:

```
<!--...-->
<h3><a href='post/'+{{ _id }}>{{ post.title }}
<!--...-->
```

I know it's not much to go on but I don't really know how to start it. I have explored the internet for answers but only came up for answers that had the HTML in the python file. I would definitely prefer to not have to put all of this into the same python file because the html file is about 50 lines of code and my code is already messy enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Why would you need to put this in the Python file? What's wrong with the template code that you have? Have you read anything about Flask or Jinja2?

Comment: I'm trying to ask how to put a variable from an external python file into the html code. I would have the code embedded in the python file, but I prefer to be able to easily use css and have the file laid out nicely, which I can't do if the code is in the python file. The problem with the template code is that the id for the post isn't added on to the end of the url, so it goes to /post/ instead of /post/1.